# Writing sample producer and consumer with spring integration and rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration

I try to write sample producer & consumer with SpringIntegration and RabbitMQ.

Here My rabbit.xml config file:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" />
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
<rabbit:queue name="queue.request" />
<rabbit:queue name="queue.response" />
<rabbit:direct-exchange name="exchange.main">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="queue.request" key="binding.queue.request"/>
        <rabbit:binding queue="queue.response" key="binding.queue.response" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

and

producer.xml file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/zcore/integration/rabbit.xml" />
<int:channel id="request" />
<int:channel id="response" />
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="request" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" 
    exchange-name="exchange.main" routing-key="binding.queue.request"       
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="response" queue-names="queue.response"
     connection-factory="connectionFactory" />  
<int:gateway id="baseGateway" service-interface="org.zcoreframework.integration.gateway.BaseGateway"
    default-request-channel="request" default-reply-channel="response" />
```

and

consumer.xml file:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/zcore/integration/rabbit.xml" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.zcoreframework" />
<int:channel id="request" /> 
<int:channel id="response" />
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="request" queue-names="queue.request"
     connection-factory="connectionFactory" />  
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="response" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" 
    exchange-name="exchange.main" routing-key="binding.queue.response" />
<int:service-activator ref="messageConsumer" method="onMessage" input-channel="request"
    output-channel="response" />
```

and I wrote this snipped code for send message and get the response:

```
@Autowired
BaseGateway baseGateway;

@Test
public void testHelloWorld() {

        CallMethodMessage callMethodMessage = new CallMethodMessage();
        callMethodMessage.setMethod("test");
        callMethodMessage.setArgs(null);
        System.out.print("send & receive ");            
        ReturnModel returnModel = this.baseGateway.SendWait(callMethodMessage);         
        //this.baseGateway.FireForget(callMethodMessage);
}
```

and this is my interface

```
public interface BaseGateway {

    @Gateway
    public void FireForget(CallMethodMessage method);

    @Gateway
    public ReturnModel SendWait(CallMethodMessage method);

}
```

OK now I run consumer separately then for the first one I run producer with method FireForget and everything is OK, cosumer gets it and prints a message but when I run with SendWait method the cosumer gets it but not return anything and the producer waits to get the response, How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correlation for the reply

```
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="request" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" 
    exchange-name="exchange.main" routing-key="binding.queue.request"       
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="response" queue-names="queue.response"
     connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
```

Use an outbound-gateway instead; you can configure it with a Rabbit Template with a `<reply-listener/>` as [discussed in the Spring AMQP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply).

And use an inbound gateway on the consumer side.

Comment: I changed my code and use outbound and inbound gateway as you mentioned and everything is OK when the passed object between producer and consumer is primitive like String or int but when I try to pass POJO class I get this error : can not convet value of type byte [[]] to required type ....

Comment: You need an appropriate `MessageConverter`; the framework provides a convenient `JsonMessageConverter` that uses Jackson to convert POJOs to/from Json, as long as your POJO is Jackson-friendly. The default converter (`SimpleMessageConverter`) handles String. byte[] and Java Serialization. Java serialization requires POJOs that are Serializable - otherwise an empty message is sent. So, use a `JsonMessageSerializer` or make your POJO Serializable (but JSON is generally considered a better choice for AMQP because it's polyglot friendly).